# IIS 7 Custom Error Page without Web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, web-config, custom-error-handling

Is there any way to set a custom error page in IIS 7 without creating a web.config?

Unfortunately researching this particular topic has been very difficult because there are SO many articles on how to do it with a web.config.  What I'm looking for is either buried beneath the 8 million results I don't want or it's not possible.

Comment: Yes, there is. It involves either subscribing to the Application_Error event in Global.asax or by writing a custom ErrorHandlerAttribute. What exactly are you trying to achieve and what are your constraints and precise requirements. Also what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please write your comment as an answer. It's correct and exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I've posted my comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. It involves either subscribing to the `Application_Error` event in `Global.asax` or by writing a custom `ErrorHandlerAttribute`.

Answer (score 1):

Darin already gave the correct answer, but I want to go into a little more depth.

In any ASP.NET application, given it is Web Forms, MVC, or raw ASP.NET, you can always use `Application_Error` Global.asax. If your ASP.NET application does not have a Global.asax, all you need to do is right-click your project in Solution Explorer, Add New Item, and choose Global Application Class. You should only have this option available if you don't already have one.
[image: Add new Global Application Class]

In your Global.asax, if you don't already see it, you can add `Application_Error` as shown below:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) {

}
```

This will be called automatically by ASP.NET whenever there is an error. But as stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3.aspx), this is not perfect. Specifically:

> An error handler that is defined in the Global.asax file will only
>   catch errors that occur **during processing of requests by the ASP.NET
>   runtime**. For example, it will catch the error if a user requests an
>   .aspx file that does not occur in your application. **However, it does
>   not catch the error if a user requests a nonexistent .htm file**. For
>   non-ASP.NET errors, you can create a custom handler in Internet
>   Information Services (IIS). **The custom handler will also not be called
>   for server-level errors**.

In `Application_Error` you can process the uncaught exception with `Server.GetLastError()`. This will provide you the `Exception` that was thrown, or `null`. I am not sure why this handler would be called if an exception didn't occur, but I believe that it is possible.

To redirect the user, use `Response.Redirect()`. Whatever you pass for the `url` is going to be sent directly to the browser without any further processing, so you can't use application-relative paths. To do that I would use this method in combination with `VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute()`. For example:

```
Response.Redirect( VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute( "~/Error.aspx" ) );
```

This redirect will be a 302 (temporary redirect) rather than a 301 (permanent), which is what you want in the case of handling errors. It's worth noting that this overload of `Response.Redirect` is the same as calling the overload `Response.Redirect(url, endResponse: true)`. This method works by throwing an exception, which is not ideal in terms of performance. Instead, call `Response.Redirect(url, false)` immediately followed by `Response.Complete​Request()`.

If you're using ASP.NET MVC, `[HandleError]` is also an option. Place this attribute on your Controller or on an Action within a controller. When this attribute is present, MVC will display the Error view, found in the ~/Views/Shared folder.

But you can make this even easier for yourself. You can automatically add this attribute to call Controllers in your project by creating a `FilterConfig` class in your project. Example:

```
public class FilterConfig {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters) {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

And then add `FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters( GlobalFilters.Filters );` to your `Application_Start()` in Global.asax.

You can read more about the `HandleErrorAttribute` at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute(v=vs.118).aspx.

But as stated above, both of these methods will never cover absolutely all errors that can occur during the processing of your application. It's not possible to provide the best user experience for all possible errors without using Web.config or configuring IIS manually.